# Prime ng 11.4.0 ripple animations not working

Tags: typescript, primeng

I have successfully installed primeng in my angular app ! styles works fine but ripple animations on button click not working !

In my app component -

```
    import { PrimeNGConfig } from 'primeng/api';

    @Component({
        selector: 'app-root',
        templateUrl: './app.component.html'
    })

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private primengConfig: PrimeNGConfig) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.primengConfig.ripple = true;
    }

}
```

Also I have imported BrowserAnimationsModule in my app module!
but still its not working! let me know if I am missing something!

Answer (score 6):

A summary for ripple effect on PrimeNG buttons :

Ripple effect is enabled globally by the `PrimeNGConfig` object. You must set the `ripple` property to `true`. Personnally, I prefer to do it inside the `APP_INITIALIZER` token, not in `AppComponent` :

**app.module.ts**

```
import { APP_INITIALIZER, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { PrimeNGConfig } from 'primeng/api';

const initializeAppFactory = (primeConfig: PrimeNGConfig) => () => {
      // ......
      primeConfig.ripple = true;
    };

     @NgModule({
        // .....
        providers: [
           {
              provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
              useFactory: initializeAppFactory,
              deps: [PrimeNGConfig],
              multi: true,
           },
        ]
     })
    export class AppModule {}
```

Ripple effect **only works** with the help of `pRipple` directive from the `RippleModule`. This directive internally check if the `ripple` property from `PrimeNGConfig` is set to `true`.

The `p-button` component's already using `pRipple` directive **inside his template**. So, if you have enabled ripple effect globally, **you have nothing more to do** and you don't have to import `RippleModule`.

The confusing parts :

BUT, if you use an html button element with the `pButton` directive, **you won't have ripple effect by default**. You must manually add the `pRipple` directive and import `RippleModule`. (`<button pButton pRipple ....>TEST</button>`).

Comment: THIS is definetly the right answer. Although I'll would like to add that you should explain how to use APP_INITIALIZER or the setting using app.component.

Comment: Ty ! I added an example with the use of APP_INITIALIZER :)

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you are import and mention the **ripple module** in you app.module.ts file.

Can you please refer the link : https://primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/button

[Reference image to find a solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KuU93.png)

Answer (score -4):

You need to install also `primeflex` and `web-animations-js` dependencies via the cli.

And make sure you have added also in your html the pRipple directive:

```html
<button pButton type="button" label="click" pRipple></button>
```

Comment: Ripple is not related to primeflex, here is the default setup link form primeng
https://primeng.org/ripple#style